# Trying to design Billiard game in HTML to make jQuery game - My First Project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am taking a whirl at my first project.  I am learning as I go.  I am trying to build a Billiard Game with jQuery.  I am at the very beginning.  I need to line up the balls first.  Can anyone give me some ideas.  So far this is where I am.  I need to initiate the balls like 5,4,3,2,1 and at the center of the table.

```
<body>

    <div id="container" class="table-layout">

        <div class="left-top">
            <div class="pocket"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-top">
            <div class="pocket"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="left-center">
            <div class="pocket"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-center">
            <div class="pocket"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="left-bottom">
            <div class="pocket"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-bottom">
            <div class="pocket"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="ball-holder">
            <div class="holder-row">
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(1)</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(2)</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(3)</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(4)</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(5)</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="holder-row">
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(6)</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(7)</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(8)</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(9)</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="holder-row">
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(10)</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(11)</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(12)</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="holder-row">    
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(13)</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(14)</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="holder-row">
                <div class="ball">
                    <h1>(15)</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="qball"></div>

    </div>


</body>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
background:green;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {

}

.table-layout {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 450px;
height: 600px;
border: 2px solid gold
}

.ball-holder {
width: 300px;
margin: -100px auto;
}

.holder-row {
display: block;
width: 300px;
text-align: center;
}

.ball {
width:30px;
height:30px;
border-radius:100%;
background-color:red;
display: inline-block;
}

.qball {
width:30px;
height:30px;
border-radius:100%;
background-color:white;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 220px;
}

h1 {
text-align:center;
font-size:10px;
font-family:arial;
color:white;
}

.pocket {
width:40px;
height:40px;
border-radius:100%;
border:2px solid black;
background-color:black;
display: inline-block;
}

.left-top {

}

.right-top {
margin-left: 405px;
margin-top: -48px;
}

.left-center {

}

.right-center {
margin-left: 405px;

}

.left-bottom {

}

.right-bottom {
margin-left: 405px;
}
```

Comment: First and most imrotant: don't wrap the ball rows in `div`s. You will not be able to easily break them apart later. use `position:absolute;` instead.

Comment: Have a look at this 2d physic engine: http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with what you currently have to continue to learn, you will have to think about the objects that you need when playing pool. One of the missing pieces that I would say that you could use is a holder - don't know what it is called in pool - that the balls will go into. You can see code that I have added for your review to see if it helps you:

http://codepen.io/pertrai1/pen/mkKna

Comment: Just for anyone wondering, that tool is called a rack or a triangle.

Comment: So I fixed it up a bit, still having problems etting the pockets the way I want them.  Can anyone check my code and make any recommendations?

Comment: @Doug - With the way that you have it setup now, I would consider adding a container for the pool table that has a relative positioning which you can then position the pockets based off of the container for the pool table

Comment: So, would I then place the container also in the css file to set the parameters?

Comment: I guess its beginning to take shape, but the gutters aren't where they should be and the ball rack moved lower.  How would I go about adjusting that?

Comment: @Doug read up on CSS positioning--namely `position: absolute`